# Cannot find Visual Studio 2015 Community version for OS X

Tags: macos, visual-studio

Where can I download Visual Studio 2015 Community version for OS X. [Here](https://www.visualstudio.com/) I download and I get and `exe` file, so think it is wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015 Community does not have a version for OS X. VS2015 can *target* OS X and iOS as build platforms, but the IDE only runs on Windows.

There is a different product called [Visual Studio Code](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/code-vs) that is cross-platform for Windows, OS X, and Linux. It is currently in a preview release, and can be downloaded from the above link.

Comment: Visual Studio Code is something like Sublime or Notepad++, right?

Comment: It looks to be more on par with something like Adobe's [Brackets](http://brackets.io).